# Is load balancing with sticky sessions limited to a single load balancing server?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, sticky-session

If you make a setup with multiple load balancers, can it still support sticky sessions (e.g. cookie based)?

Since sticky sessions rely on state stored at the load balancer, the different load balancers would have to exchange that information. So technically I believe it is feasible.

Are there any free/paying solutions which can be deployed on prem that provide this feature?

I guess load balancers of AWS, Azure, etc implement such a feature?

Comment: just a question why you want to achieve sticky-session with load balancer...

Comment: websocket emulation via long polling